# Cannot create proto file. Language must be specified error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Click Add New Item on the context menu of Protos folder.
Select Protocol Buffer File
Click Add
This Error :

[image]

Comment: How did you open VS?  Looks like you do not have a project file so programming language is not specified.  Best way of fixing issue is to create a new project in VS and then use menu Project : Add Existing Item to add files to the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that exists in Visual Studio and you just need to update it to solve it.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-create-proto-file-language-must-be-specifie/1552266